# My button onClick recenter for OpenLayers doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick, openlayers

I'm building an angular application using openlayers that when I click a button it will recenter my map .I'm trying to re-center my map when I onClick to a button but it doesnt work.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCenter' of undefined.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance !

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj'
import {view} from 'ol/View';
import * as ol from 'openlayers';

export class AppComponent {
  distance = 60;
  points: Array<{ x: number; y: number; }> = [];
  position : Array<{ x: number; y: number; id: string; radius: number,color:string, place:string}> = 
  [
      {x:11.5820,y:48.1351,id:"munich",radius:20, color:"red", place:"m"},
      {x:13.388866,y:52.517071,id:"berlin", radius:40,color:"blue", place:"b"},
  ];

  coords = {
    berlin: [13.388866, 52.517071]
 };

 onClick (city: string) {
  view.setCenter({
     center: fromLonLat(this.coords[city]),
     duration: 2000
  });
}

  mapOnClick(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    const map = evt.map;
    // this bit checks if user clicked on a feature
    const p = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
     function(feature, layer) {
      console.log("got feature" + feature.getId());
      return feature;

    });
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='berlin' (click)="onClick('berlin')">Zoom to Berlin</button>
```

Comment: Seems that view is undefined. You should initialize it.. like:  `view: new View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })`

Comment: it doesn't work :  ol_View__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.View is not a constructor

Comment: you should import it like:  `import View from 'ol/View';`
and then:
`var view = new View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 2
      });`
check this example [link](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html)

Comment: Please read also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to **recenter** there must already be a view, but if it was constructed inside the map constructor there won't be a view variable and you will need to reference it using map.getView().  Also setCenter() doesn't do animated recentering.  Assuming your map variable is `map` try:

```
  map.getView().animate({
     center: fromLonLat(this.coords[city]),
     duration: 2000
  })
```

Comment: how do i declare map variable as map? Sorry im new to Angular and openlayers

Comment: I'm not familar with Angular but this question may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601947/setting-the-map-as-a-variable-in-angular6-openlayers

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this once just for suggestion,

```
import OlView from 'ol/View';

view: OlView;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.view = new OlView({
      center: fromLonLat(this.coords[city]),
      zoom: 3
    });
  }
```

I hope its solve your problem if you received proper data for `this.coords[city]` variable. You need to pass data like this, `center: fromLonLat([6.661594, 10.32371])`.

For more Reference,
[Use OpenLayers 4 with Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283679/use-openlayers-4-with-angular-5)

You may get some idea from this above url example.

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: it doesnt have effect to the map

Comment: i declared the map early on in my html  
<aol-view [zoom]="14">
    <aol-coordinate [x]="13.388866" [y]="52.517071" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"></aol-coordinate>
  </aol-view>